# angularjs data not showing in view after retrieving from request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Everyone.
I am facing a problem while loading data in the view.
my controller is

```
app.controller('AccountController', function(dataFactory,$scope,$http){ 
getResultsPage(1);
function getResultsPage(pageNumber) {

  if(! $.isEmptyObject($scope.libraryTemp)){
      if($.isEmptyObject($scope.searchText)){
        $scope.searchText = '';
        }
        if($.isEmptyObject($scope.account_type)){
        $scope.account_type = '';
        }
      dataFactory.httpRequest('/angular_project/public/accounts?search='+$scope.searchText+'&account_type='+$scope.account_type+'&page='+pageNumber).then(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data.account.data;
        $scope.accountType = data.account_type;
        $scope.totalItems = data.account.total;
        $scpoe.perpage = data.perpage;
      });
  }else{
    dataFactory.httpRequest('/angular_project/public/accounts?page='+pageNumber).then(function(data) {
      $scope.data = data.account.data;
      $scope.accountType = data.account_type;
      $scope.totalItems = data.account.total;
      $scope.perpage = data.perpage;
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
$scope.accounts_detail = function(id){
  dataFactory.httpRequest('accounts_detail/'+id).then(function(data) {console.log(data);
      $scope.sales_items_detail = data.sales_items_detail;
      $scope.mall_roakker_detail = data.mall_roakker_detail;
      $scope.transection_detail = data.transection_detail;
      console.log($scope.sales_items_detail);
      $scope.ddd = 'asdfasdf';
      //getResultsPage(1);
  });
}     
});
```

my first view is:

```
<tbody>
                    <tr dir-paginate="value in data | itemsPerPage:perpage" total-items="totalItems">
                        <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ value.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ value.address }}</td>
                        <td>{{ value.title }}</td>
                        <td>{{ value.check_from }}</td>
                        <td>{{ value.check_to }}</td>
                        <td>
                        <button data-toggle="modal" ng-click="edit(value.id)" data-target="#edit-data" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                        <a href="#/accounts_detail" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="accounts_detail(value.id)">Account Detail</a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

problem is that while I click on Account Detail link data loaded from the database through but not showing in the related view that is.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" data-background-color="purple">
            <h4 class="title">Account Detail</h4>

        </div>                   
        <div class="card-content table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered pagin-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Item Name</th>
                        <th>Rate</th>
                        <th>Weight</th>                            
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in mall_roakker_detail">
                        <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ x.title }}</td>
                        <td>{{ x.rate }}</td>
                        <td>{{ x.weight }}</td>                            
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>

                </tfoot>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in this view, data is not showing but console shows this data.
[image]

anybody can help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what happens if you console log the  $scope.mall_roakker_detail in the button click? what is the output?

Comment: see console out put in edited picture

Comment: can you also show the whole html output .. or make a plunker.. and what i asked was to console.log($scope.mall_roakker_detail) to see if the scope gets the values ..  .

Comment: is dir-paginate a custom directive , is it Isolated scope?

Comment: dir pagination view is working but when i click on account_detail() function then i load the second view and in second view data is not loading

Answer (score 0):

I think in your js file your `$scope.accounts_detail = function (id){}` not calling from anywhere. 
call this function like

```
$scope.accounts_detail(id);
```

Comment: i am calling this function here <a href="#/accounts_detail" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="accounts_detail(value.id)">Detail</a>

Comment: can you create some plunker or fiddle for this?